# Jenkins: allow local checkout

Tags: jenkins, automation

It's the first time I'm using Jenkins. I created a new folder with just one file and created a git repository in it. Then I set up Jenkins with that repository.

What I get now is this error:

> ERROR: Checkout of Git remote 'path\hello' aborted because it
> references a local directory, which may be insecure. You can allow
> local checkouts anyway by setting the system property
> 'hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT' to true. Finished:
> FAILURE

I tried to start jenkins using this command:

```
C:\Users\userName\.jdks\zulu11.56.19-ca-jdk11.0.15-win_x64\bin\java.exe -jar jenkins.war  hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true
```

But it didn't work.
How can I set this "allow local checkout" to true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define properties using option -D:
`-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true`

Comment: When I try:
java -Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true -jar jenkins.war,
I get this exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Ok, now it works. The property needs to be between quotes.

 -D"hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"

Comment: It works great for me as-is: `-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true`

Comment: I also had to use quotes `-D"hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"`. Jenkins 2.387.1 on Windows.

Comment: For me it does not work at all. I have set the system property correctly and when I open the script console of jenkins and type `System.getProperty("hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT")` and run it, I get `Result: true`. However, when I build, I still get the same error: `You can allow local checkouts anyway by setting the system property 'hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT' to true.` So jenkins is broken. Using 2.387.3

Comment: Feature only exists in documentation and error message but not handled in the code:
https://github.com/search?q=org%3Ajenkinsci%20hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT&type=code

Comment: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68571

Comment: Where to add this option in config file? On CentOS7, I tried to add /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service and restart jenkins service, but still get this error.

Comment: for some lazy monkey like me, using services, add this to the jenkins.xml solved the problem.
```<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx4g -Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "D:\Soft\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%LocalAppData%\Jenkins\war"</arguments>
```   
PS: restart needed.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue the solution was:

`-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true` needs to be **BEFORE** -jar jenkins.war in the command line call.

The solution is provided from the below recourse:

https://community.jenkins.io/t/checkout-of-git-remote-aborted-because-it-references-a-local-directory/4110

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu edit config:

```
sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
```

Add line:

```
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```

Restsart service:

```
service jenkins restart
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Check config:

```
systemctl cat jenkins
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am running Jenkins on WSL2 (Ubuntu), I edited the file "jenkins" located at /etc/default, added the line:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```

right below an existing line, like so:

```
# Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```

After saving the file, did a "**service jenkins restart**" and it worked for me, now whenever Jenkins is started I don't have to specify the option manually.

Comment: For ubuntu edit /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service

Answer (score 0):

For RedHat/CentOS, edit config file at: `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` 
Find: `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"` 
Add below:
`JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"`
Then restart: `sudo systemctl restart jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using macOS and installed Jenkins-LTS using Homebrew, you only need to edit the `/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist` file and add `<string>-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true</string>` before `<string>-jar</string>`. Save the file and run `brew services restart jenkins-lts`. The complete contents of this file after the edits:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aqua</string>
        <string>Background</string>
        <string>LoginWindow</string>
        <string>StandardIO</string>
        <string>System</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java</string>
        <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
        <string>-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
        <string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
        <string>--httpPort=8080</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```