# Jenkins in Docker Git Plugin allow local checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This same question was asked but not with jenkins in a Docker container
[Jenkins: allow local checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341686/jenkins-allow-local-checkout)

I had jenkins running in a docker container and was able to execute pipeline jobs with no problem.
After installing the container recently on a new machine I'm getting:

```
ERROR: Checkout of Git remote 'file:///usr/src/' aborted because it references a local directory, which may be insecure. You can allow local checkouts anyway by setting the system property 'hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT' to true.
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried this script in init.d

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import java.util.logging.LogManager
/* Jenkins home directory */ 
def jenkinsHome = Jenkins.instance.getRootDir().absolutePath
def logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("")
/* Replace the Key and value with the values you want to set.*/
/* System.setProperty(key, value) */
System.setProperty("hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT", "true")
logger.info("Jenkins Startup Script: set GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT to true . Script location : ${jenkinsHome}/init.groovy.d ")
```

I tried this inside the docker container

```
jenkins@3d5e0ebf919e:/$ java -D"hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true" -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.warns.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true" -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2022-05-28 20:26:27.644+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @758ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2022-05-28 20:26:27.744+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2022-05-28 20:26:27.792+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2022-05-28 20:26:27.876+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.43.v20210629; built: 2021-06-30T11:07:22.254Z; git: 526006ecfa3af7f1a27ef3a288e2bef7ea9dd7e8; jvm 11.0.15+10
2022-05-28 20:26:28.162+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2022-05-28 20:26:28.204+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2022-05-28 20:26:28.204+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2022-05-28 20:26:28.205+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2022-05-28 20:26:28.694+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2022-05-28 20:26:28.869+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@36c54a56{Jenkins v2.332.3,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2022-05-28 20:26:28.892+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStop: Stopped ServerConnector@206a70ef{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2022-05-28 20:26:28.893+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#stopScavenging: node0 Stopped scavenging
2022-05-28 20:26:28.901+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextDestroyed: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStop(ServletHandler.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStop(SecurityHandler.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStop(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStop(SessionHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:94)
    at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:318)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:205)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at Main._main(Main.java:304)
    at Main.main(Main.java:108)
2022-05-28 20:26:28.905+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStop: Stopped w.@36c54a56{Jenkins v2.332.3,/,null,STOPPED}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:261)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:538)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
2022-05-28 20:26:28.908+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:194)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at Main._main(Main.java:304)
    at Main.main(Main.java:108)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
    ... 14 more
2022-05-28 20:26:28.909+0000 [id=1] SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:194)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at Main._main(Main.java:304)
    at Main.main(Main.java:108)
```

In jenkins system properties i see `hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT    true`

Still the problem persists
Running Jenkins 2.332.3

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

ARG user
ARG password
ARG git_password
ARG branch

USER jenkins
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh \
    cloudbees-folder \
    antisamy-markup-formatter \
    build-timeout \
    credentials-binding \
    timestamper \
    ws-cleanup \
    ant \
    gradle \
    workflow-aggregator \
    github-organization-folder \
    pipeline-stage-view \
    git \
    subversion \
    ssh-slaves \
    matrix-auth \
    pam-auth \
    ldap \
    email-ext \
    mailer \
    ssh \
    build-user-vars-plugin \
    yet-another-build-visualizer \
    rebuild 
ENV JENKINS_USER ${user}
ENV JENKINS_PASS ${password}
ENV GIT_PASS ${git_password}
ENV CURRENT_BRANCH ${branch}
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Dhudson,plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
COPY init.groovy.d/dev/*.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home
```

Still the problem exists:
Any ideas to fix this?
Any way to make my git directory not "a local directory"?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled on this problem too. Based on this [answer](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/issues/5222#issuecomment-1155158407), you just need to add the env variable when starting the container.

```
docker run ... --env JAVA_OPTS="-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was in the init.groovy.d/dev/jobs.groovy file

After this line:

`def scm = new GitSCM("file:///usr/src/");`

I added this line

`scm.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true`

Answer (score 0):

Your ENV JAVA_OPTS are overwriting each other. Try putting them on the same line.

`ENV JAVA_OPTS -Dhudson,plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false`

The reason I say that is I added the below to my dockerfile and it works great.

`ENV JAVA_OPTS -Dhudson,plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using docker-compose, then you need to add the system property as below -

```
environment:
 - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```