# jenkins allow local checkout in ububtu 20.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins

i am trying to add my local git project in jenkins for that i have chosen scm as Git and added the project path in the Repository URL
as  `file://///home/use/git/my-project/`
credentials as `none` when i click on build i got the following build error

```
Started by user abc
Checking out git file://///home/use/git/my-project/ into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-scrapping-project@script/345944b463ac0a944e5821c03471b5f079c5f64d079aa5da9d48040a97ce6de5 to read 
ERROR: Checkout of Git remote 'file://///home/user/git/my-project//' aborted because it references a local directory, which may be insecure. You can allow local checkouts anyway by setting the system property 'hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT' to true.
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
Finished: FAILURE
```

i found this solution [Jenkins: allow local checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341686/jenkins-allow-local-checkout)
i have added following lines in /etc/default/jenkins

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
 Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
 Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"

JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```

then restarted jenkins

```
service jenkins restart
```

did not resolve the issue so i have added the following line in  `/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service

```
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
```

`and restarted the service

```
service jenkins restart
systemctl daemon-reload
```

the error persists

Comment: It should be a system property not a java opt. try `export hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true`

Comment: in which file should i add